# Unity - Asset bundle not creating properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I am creating asset bundle of a 3D object in unity. It is not creating with transform values (scale, rotation, position). But while I debug its values are coming correctly but after bundling and loading into my app its reset to default value.

I am using the following script for exporting 3D object to asset bundle

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class CreateAssetBundles : Editor
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create Asset Bundle")]
    static void CreateBundle()
    {
        string bundlePath = "Assets/AssetBundle/";
        Object[] selectedAssets = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(Object), SelectionMode.Assets);
        GameObject gameobject = (GameObject) selectedAssets[0];
        string name = gameobject.name;
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(Selection.activeObject, selectedAssets, bundlePath+name+ ".unity3d", BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies | BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets, BuildTarget.Android);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Asset bundle manager in your project from following link
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#!/content/45836
and Go to Assets  ->AssetBundle-> Build Asset bundle
this will create asset bundle in folder name Assetbundle outside the Asset folder of project